# How to add ngClick to an existing element

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

So I have some HTML that I do not control.

```
<div id="myDiv">
 Stuff inside my div...
</div>
```

I want to add an ngClick to it. If I could control the html, I would just do this

```
<div id="myDiv" ng-click="doSomething()">
 Stuff inside my div...
</div>
```

But like I said, I can't change the html. If this was jQuery, I would just do

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
  doSomething();
});
```

How do I do this in Angularjs? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Judging from the downvotes, it seems like you guys are not happy with what I am trying to do here, so let me explain.

I am using AngularUI in my app. AngularUI has all these templates that they insert. For example

```
<accordion-heading></accordion-heading>
```

becomes

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a href="" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-transclude="heading">
        <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Heading</span>
      </a>
    </h4>
</div>
```

I want to add ngClick to "panel-title". I COULD overwrite the template and add it, but I don't want to do that. Coming from jQuery, it makes sense to just listen to a click event on "panel-title". How it is done Angular? Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to transform an existing web page you have no control over into an angular app? Good luck with that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find the element, smth like: `angular.element(//selector here);` then add attribute you need(ng-click), `.attr('ng-click', '//whatever should be here')`, and then compile it with angular `$compile`.

But. I feel sad that you have to do this, I hope you'll find a possibility to change html.

[Docs for compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It make sense. I am getting downvotes for my question, so let me explain what I am doing. I am using AngularUI to do some stuff with my app. AngularUI has a lot of templates that they use to build a specific html snippets. I could over-write those templates to add ngClick where I need them, but I find that to be very heavy handed. I just want a simple way to listen to click events and fire off what I need. I am coming from jQuery, so this line of thinking make sense to me. How does an angular person do it?

Comment: hm, I don't really using AngularUI, but I've check out some examples form here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (I assume you were talking about this). What you can do? Some directives from there provides functionality for adding callbacks, if not, you can try watching for model using `$watch(..)` and do actions depending on that. I mean click somewhere **should** change something, so you can listen for changes instead of watching for actions.